# Rails how to create a new record of a parent model from the child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 rails models, a security and stock_quote model, which are as follows

```
class StockQuote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :security, class_name: "Security", foreign_key: 'security_id'
end

class Security < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stock_quotes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In the rails console when i try doing,

```
 a = Security.create(security: "Goldman Sachs", category: "Investment Banking")
 b = a.stock_quotes.first
 c = b.security.create(security: "Facebook", category: "Tech")
```

The last query generates the following error

```
 Security Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "securities".* FROM "securities"  WHERE "securities"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 NoMethodError: undefined method `create' for #<Security:0xbbd2d78>
```

What I'm i doing wrongly because my associations are correctly defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead `c = b.security.create(security: "Facebook", category: "Tech")` you need `b.create_security(security: "Facebook", category: "Tech")`. This similar to

```
 b.security = Security.new;
 b.security.save; b.security
```

Read doc for [`ActiveRecord::Base#belongs_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to)

Comment: I've tried the above on my code but I'm getting an error...check my edit

Comment: my answer right, now you have another problem and you should post question and explain. Bad practices pull all problem in one questions.

Comment: I've done that and posted the question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537226/rails-4-1-0-no-method-error-when-trying-to-update-a-parent-table-from-a-child-ta