# Rails 4.1.0 No Method error when trying to update a parent table from a child table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have 2 rails models, a security and stock_quote model, which are as follows

```
class StockQuote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :security, class_name: "Security", foreign_key: 'security_id'

  def self.price_on(date)
    where("date(created_at) = ?", date).sum(:high)
  end
    feed_url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1ncyK8uXoeLobVkdiSKQcYJr2joK_uN5QSBB3814GKaw/od6/public/values"
  def self.update_from_feed(feed_url)
    feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
        unless feed.is_a?(Fixnum)
          add_entries(feed.entries)
        else
          puts "not an array\n"
        end

   end


     private

     def self.add_nonexistent_security(entry)
   a = StockQuote.create_security(security: entry.title.capitalize, category: "Uncategorized")
     end

     def self.save_entry(entry,security_id)
        unless exists? guid: entry.id
                contents = entry.content.split(',').map {|n| n.split(" ").last }
                parsed_contents = contents.map{ |x| x.scan(/[\d\.-]+/)[0] }.map(&:to_f)
                parsed_contents.each do |content|
                create!(
                  security_id: b.id,
                  yesterday: content[0],
                  current: content[1],
                  change: content[2],
                  percentage_change: content[3],
                  high: content[4],
                  low: content[5],
                  published_at: entry.updated,
                  guid: entry.id
                )
                end
     end
end

class Security < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stock_quotes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When I go to the console and do

```
c = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1ncyK8uXoeLobVkdiSKQcYJr2joK_uN5QSBB3814GKaw/od6/public/values"
StockQuote.update_from_feed(c)
```

I get this

```
(0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "securities"  WHERE "securities"."security" = 'Sameer africa'
NoMethodError: undefined method `create_security' for #<Class:0xbf84f98>
```

I haev now provided the full data set and model look of stock_quote.rb I'm using feedzija  gem to fetch andparse the rss

Comment: @Baloo this is another question.

Comment: It wasn't before the edit

Comment: You have a typo. You probably mean `a = self.create_security(security: entry.title.capitalize, category: "Uncategorized")`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method for the child model which belongs to the parent model. Only has_many or has_one has such methods create, or build. But, there is some other method which uses this pattern **build_** or **create_** for **belongs_to** association.

So if you do it like this,

```
b.create_security(security: "Facebook", category: "Tech")
```

It will work fine.

Comment: I have posted my full model and asyou can see I've tried that. Check the edit

Comment: How can you call create_security method on class. It is not class method. It is instance method. First fetch the stockQuote. 

stockQuote = StockQuote.find(1)
stockQuote.create_security(attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Create is a class method but you are using it in an instance of a security

```
b.security.create(security: "Facebook", category: "Tech")
```

In the next part #create_security is used as a class method it has to be called on the instance of a StackQuote

Comment: This does not work but instead return this on console    (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "securities"  WHERE "securities"."security" = 'Sameer africa'
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "stock_quotes" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-05-08 09:17:23.891679"], ["updated_at", "2014-05-08 09:17:23.891679"]]